# Algorithm to calculate the number of 1s for a range of numbers in binary

Tags: algorithm, language-agnostic, binary

So I just got back for the **ACM Programing competition** and did pretty well but there was one problem that not one team got.

The Problem.

> Start with an integer N0 which is greater than 0. Let N1 be the number of ones in the binary representation of N0. So, if `N0 = 27`, `N1 = 4`. For all `i > 0`, let Ni be the number of ones in the binary representation of `Ni-1`. This sequence will always converge to one. For any starting number, N0, let K be the minimum value of i >= 0 for which N1 = 1. For example, if N0 = 31, then N1 = 5, N2 = 2, N3 = 1, so K = 3.
>
> Given a range of consecutive numbers and a value of X how many numbers in the range have a K value equal to X?
>
> **Input**
>   There will be several test cases in the input. Each test case will consist of three integers on a single line: 
>   `LO HI X`
>   Where `LO` and `HI` (1 <= `LO` <= `HI` <= 10^18) are the lower and upper limits of a range of integers, and `X` (0 <= `X` <= 10) is the target value for K. The input will end with a line of three 0s.
>
> **Output**
>   For each test case output a single integer, representing the number of integers in the range from `LO` to `HI` (inclusive) which have a K value equal to X in the input. Print each Integer on its own line with no spaces. Do not print any blank lines between answers.

#### Sample Input

```
31 31 3
31 31 1
27 31 1
27 31 2
1023 1025 1
1023 1025 2
0 0 0
```

#### Sample Output

```
1
0
0
3
1
1
```

---

If you guys want I can include our answer or our problem, because finding for a small range is easy but I will give you a hint first your program needs to run in *seconds* not minutes.  We had a successful solution but not an efficient algorithm to use a range similar to

```
48238 10^18 9
```

Anyway good luck and if the community likes these we had some more we could not solve that could be some good brain teasers for you guys. The competition allows you to use Python, C++, or Java—all three are acceptable in an answer.

---

So as a hint my coach said to think of how binary numbers count rather than checking every bit.  I think that gets us a lot closer.

Comment: If this is not somthing cribbed from [project euler](http://projecteuler.net/) it should put be there.

Comment: A little about the competition for you. It's run buy the ACM and sponsored by IBM.  It is for undergrad college students.  The competition lasts 5 hour and you are on a team of three with one work station that is not connected to the internet.  The only resources you are allowed is a 12x12x2inch box full of docs you bring in.  I am not aware of the source of this problem but I think it was written by professors at the college where the competition is held.

Comment: Without the test cases is hard to prove a solution right or wrong. Can you provide them?

Comment: @teto the sample input and output was the only test case we got.  They correspond

Comment: @zobgib: Which regional was this? Can you provide a link to the problem hosted at live archive?

Comment: @MAK South East regionals they do not have their problems posted yet you can access the regionals page at http://ser.cs.fit.edu/ser2010/

Comment: @zoglib: Simply saying "southeast" does not really help much - it could mean south east Europe for example. Almost all regional as well as world finals problemsets are added soon after the contest to the "ICPC Live Archive" which is an online judge where you can practice them. This problem appears in http://acm.uva.es/archive/nuevoportal/region.php?r=se&year=2010. So anyone trying out solutions can verify the correctness of their approach.

Comment: @MAK thanks very much I did not know that site existed.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

I think a key is first understanding the pattern of K values and how rapidly it grows.  Basically, you have:

```
K(1) = 0
K(X) = K(bitcount(X))+1 for X > 1
```

So finding the smallest X values for a given K we see

```
K(1) = 0
K(2) = 1
K(3) = 2
K(7) = 3
K(127) = 4
K(170141183460469231731687303715884105727) = 5
```

So for an example like `48238 10^18 9` the answer is trivially 0.  K=0 only for 1, and K=1 only for powers of 2, so in the range of interest, we'll pretty much only see K values of 2, 3 or 4, and never see K >= 5

**edit**

Ok, so we're looking for an algorithm to count the number of values with K=2,3,4 in a range of value LO..HI without iterating over the entire range.  So the first step is to find the number of values in the range with bitcount(x)==i for i = 1..59 (since we only care about values up to 10^18 and 10^18 < 2^60).  So break down the range lo..hi into subranges that are a power of 2 size and differ only in their lower n bits -- a range of the form x*(2^n)..(x+1)*(2^n)-1.  We can break down the arbitray lo..hi range into such subranges easily.  For each such subrange there will be choose(n, i) values with i+bitcount(x) set bits.
So we just add all the subranges together to get a vector of counts for 1..59, which we then iterate over, adding together those elements with the same K value to get our answer.

**edit** (fixed again to be be C89 compatible and work for lo=1/k=0)

Here's a C program to do what I previously described:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <assert.h>

int bitcount(long long x) {
    int rv = 0;
    while(x) { rv++; x &= x-1; }
    return rv; }

long long choose(long long m, long long n) {
    long long rv = 1;
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        rv *= m-i;
        rv /= i+1; }
    return rv; }

void bitcounts_p2range(long long *counts, long long base, int l2range) {
    int i;
    assert((base & ((1LL << l2range) - 1)) == 0);
    counts += bitcount(base);
    for (i = 0; i <= l2range; i++)
        counts[i] += choose(l2range, i); }

void bitcounts_range(long long *counts, long long lo, long long hi) {
    int l2range = 0;
    while (lo + (1LL << l2range) - 1 <= hi) {
        if (lo & (1LL << l2range)) {
            bitcounts_p2range(counts, lo, l2range);
            lo += 1LL << l2range; }
        l2range++; }
    while (l2range >= 0) {
        if (lo + (1LL << l2range) - 1 <= hi) {
            bitcounts_p2range(counts, lo, l2range);
            lo += 1LL << l2range; }
        l2range--; }
    assert(lo == hi+1); }

int K(int x) {
    int rv = 0;
    while(x > 1) {
        x = bitcount(x);
        rv++; }
    return rv; }

int main() {
    long long counts[64];
    long long lo, hi, total;
    int i, k;
    while (scanf("%lld%lld%d", &lo, &hi, &k) == 3) {
        if (lo < 1 || lo > hi || k < 0) break;
        if (lo == 0 || hi == 0 || k == 0) break;
        total = 0;
        if (lo == 1) {
            lo++;
            if (k == 0) total++; }
        memset(counts, 0, sizeof(counts));
        bitcounts_range(counts, lo, hi);
        for (i = 1; i < 64; i++)
            if (K(i)+1 == k)
                total += counts[i];
        printf("%lld\n", total); }
    return 0; }
```

which runs just fine for values up to 2^63-1 (LONGLONG_MAX).
For `48238 1000000000000000000 3` it gives `513162479025364957`, which certainly seems plausible

**edit**

giving the inputs of

```
48238 1000000000000000000 1
48238 1000000000000000000 2
48238 1000000000000000000 3
48238 1000000000000000000 4
```

gives outputs of

```
44
87878254941659920
513162479025364957
398959266032926842
```

Those add up to 999999999999951763 which is correct.  The value for k=1 is correct (there are 44 powers of two in that range 2^16 up to 2^59).  So while I'm not sure the other 3 values are correct, they're certainly plausible.

Comment: pst is right. You still need to write an algorithm that can handle any X value with out having to iterate through the entire range.

Comment: That answer seems very wrong, you need to be calculating the K which is the the N(i) K is not a given value. I think you are misreading the question I wouldn't mind hopping in a chat and talking about it if you are willing, because I think you are very close.

Comment: @zobgib: The problem seems to be defining K as the number of repeated bitcounts to get to the fixed point of 1, which is the same as the formula I give above.  The code I posted gives correct results for anything I can calculate by hand, including all the examples in your sample input.

Comment: The thing that seems wrong to me is the fact that if if you look at your results for the `48238 1000000000000000000 3` it says that 51% of the numbers in that range have a K of 3. That is impossible.  Maybe I am misreading your C, I am not very proficient at it, but an output that high seems unlikely.  You are really close though. I will show my coach this week and see what he thinks.

Comment: @zobgib: Why is that impossible?  It certainly seems in the right ballpark, and the totals for all K values add up to the size of the range.

Comment: I tried running your code and I get compile errors if you fix it and I can test it I will accept your answer. But according to my coach and just what I was thinking the answer is incorrect.

Comment: @zobgib: You'll have to be more specific with the error messages. The program compiles without issues using g++ under 64-bit Linux and gives the expected output.  FWIW, I've independently verified the results using my own custom script in Pari/GP.

Comment: I am using the acm-livearchive to check your answer you can submit it here... http://acm.uva.es/archive/nuevoportal/region.php?r=se&year=2010. The problem is the bittcounting.  The error message the online judge compiler gave me can be viewed here. http://pastebin.com/WAxVxEvJ.  I tried uploading it as a C file and submitting it as plaintext.  If you have any luck let me know!

Comment: @zobgib: Try submitting as a C++ file.

Comment: @zobgib: Is there a way to find out the test cases that are failing and the expected result?  The program works as expected on the sample input/output you've provided.

Comment: No the ACM-ICPC compilers are designed to give little to no information or hints to lead you to a correct answer.  I can see if I can find the input that the compiler uses, but as you can see the website is horrible to navigate.

Comment: The compile errors come from the code being C99 instead of C89; the 'wrong answer' comes from not dealing with k=0 (I was treating that as end of input, as its non-interesting -- K(1)==0 is the only value with a k of 0 -- didn't read the exact spec carefully enough).  Fixing that make the ACM judge accept the answer just fine

Comment: So Chris can you edit your code so it answers right and then I will give you bonus and accept your answer!

Comment: @zobgib -- did that yesterday.  The code still isn't truly C89 compatible as it uses `long long`, but it at least gets accepted by and passes the judge.

Answer (score 7):

The idea behind this answer can help you develop very fast solution. Having ranges 0..2^N the complexity of a potential algorithm would be O(N) in the worst case (Assuming that complexity of a long arithmetic is O(1)) If programmed correctly it should easily handle N = 1000000 in a matter of milliseconds.

Imagine we have the following values:

```
LO   =          0; (0000000000000000000000000000000)
HI   = 2147483647; (1111111111111111111111111111111)
```

The lowest possible N1 in range LO..HI is 0 
The highest possible N1 in range LO..HI is 31

So the computation of N2..NN part  is done only for one of 32 values (i.e. 0..31).
Which can be done simply, even without a computer.
Now lets compute the amount of N1=X for a range of values LO..HI

When we have X =  0 we have count(N1=X) =  1 this is the following value:

```
1   0000000000000000000000000000000
```

When we have X =  1 we have count(N1=X) = 31 these are the following values:

```
01  1000000000000000000000000000000
02  0100000000000000000000000000000
03  0010000000000000000000000000000
    ...
30  0000000000000000000000000000010
31  0000000000000000000000000000001
```

---

When we have X = 2 we have the following pattern:

```
1100000000000000000000000000000
```

How many unique strings can be formed with 29 - '0' and 2 - '1'?

Imagine the rightmost '1'(#1) is cycling from left to right, we get the following picture:

```
01  1100000000000000000000000000000
02  1010000000000000000000000000000
03  1001000000000000000000000000000
    ...
30  1000000000000000000000000000001
```

Now we've got 30 unique strings while moving the '1'(#1)  from left to right, it is now impossible to 
create a unique string by moving the '1'(#1) in any direction. This means we should move '1'(#2) to the right,
let's also reset the position of '1'(#1) as left as possible remaining uniqueness, we get:

```
01  0110000000000000000000000000000
```

now we do the cycling of '1'(#1) once again

```
02  0101000000000000000000000000000
03  0100100000000000000000000000000
    ...
29  0100000000000000000000000000001
```

Now we've got 29 unique strings, continuing this whole operation 28 times we get the following expression

```
count(N1=2) = 30 + 29 + 28 + ... + 1 = 465
```

---

When we have X = 3 the picture remains similar but we are moving '1'(#1), '1'(#2), '1'(#3)

Moving the '1'(#1) creates 29 unique strings, when we start moving '1'(#2) we get

29 + 28 + ... + 1 = 435 unique strings, after that we are left to process '1'(#3) so we have

```
29 + 28 + ... + 1 = 435
     28 + ... + 1 = 406
          ...
              + 1 = 1

435 + 406 + 378 + 351 + 325 + 300 + 276 +
253 + 231 + 210 + 190 + 171 + 153 + 136 +
120 + 105 + 091 + 078 + 066 + 055 + 045 +
036 + 028 + 021 + 015 + 010 + 006 + 003 + 001 = 4495
```

---

Let's try to solve the general case i.e. when we have N zeros and M ones.
Overall amount of permutations for the string of length (N + M) is equal to (N + M)!

The amount of '0' duplicates in this string is equal to N!
The amount of '1' duplicates in this string is equal to M!

thus receiving overall amount of unique strings formed of N zeros and M ones is

```
              (N + M)!          32!       263130836933693530167218012160000000
F(N, M) =  ============= => ========== = ====================================== = 4495
            (N!) * (M!)      3! * 29!      6 * 304888344611713860501504000000
```

**Edit:**

```
F(N, M) = Binomial(N + M, M)
```

---

Now let's consider a real life example:

```
LO   =   43797207; (0000010100111000100101011010111)
HI   = 1562866180; (1011101001001110111001000000100)
```

So how do we apply our unique permutations formula to this example? Since we don't know how
many '1' is located below LO and how many '1' is located above HI.

So lets count these permutations below LO and above HI.

Lets remember how we cycled '1'(#1), '1'(#2), ...

```
1111100000000000000000000000000 => 2080374784
1111010000000000000000000000000 => 2046820352
1111001000000000000000000000000 => 2030043136
1111000000000000000000000000001 => 2013265921

1110110000000000000000000000000 => 1979711488
1110101000000000000000000000000 => 1962934272
1110100100000000000000000000000 => 1954545664
1110100010000000000000000000001 => 1950351361
```

As you see this cycling process decreases the decimal values smoothly. So we need to count amount of
cycles until we reach HI value. But we shouldn't be counting these values by one because
the worst case can generate up to 32!/(16!*16!) = 601080390 cycles, which we will be cycling very long :)
So we need cycle chunks of '1' at once.

Having our example we would want to count the amount of cycles of a transformation

```
1111100000000000000000000000000 => 1011101000000000000000000000000
                                   1011101001001110111001000000100
```

So how many cycles causes the transformation

```
1111100000000000000000000000000 => 1011101000000000000000000000000
```

?

Lets see, the transformation:

```
1111100000000000000000000000000 => 1110110000000000000000000000000
```

is equal to following set of cycles:

```
01  1111100000000000000000000000000
02  1111010000000000000000000000000
...
27  1111000000000000000000000000001
28  1110110000000000000000000000000
```

So we need 28 cycles to transform

```
1111100000000000000000000000000 => 1110110000000000000000000000000
```

How many cycles do we need to transform

```
1111100000000000000000000000000 => 1101110000000000000000000000000
```

performing following moves we need:

```
1110110000000000000000000000000 28 cycles
1110011000000000000000000000000 27 cycles
1110001100000000000000000000000 26 cycles
...
1110000000000000000000000000011  1 cycle
```

and 1 cycle for receiving:

```
1101110000000000000000000000000  1 cycle
```

thus receiving 28 + 27 + ... + 1 + 1 = 406 + 1

but we have seen this value before and it was the result for the amount of unique permutations, which was
computed for 2 '1' and 27 '0'. This means that amount of cycles while moving

```
11100000000000000000000000000 => 01110000000000000000000000000
```

is equal to moving

```
_1100000000000000000000000000 => _0000000000000000000000000011
```

plus one additional cycle

so this means if we have M zeros and N ones and want to move the chunk of U '1' to the right we will need to
perform the following amount of cycles:

```
      (U - 1 + M)!
1 + =============== = f(U, M)
     M! * (U - 1)!
```

**Edit:**

```
f(U, M) = 1 + Binomial(U - 1 + M, M)
```

Now let's come back to our real life example:

```
    LO   =   43797207; (0000010100111000100101011010111)
    HI   = 1562866180; (1011101001001110111001000000100)
```

so what we want to do is count the amount cycles needed to perform the following
transformations (suppose N1 = 6)

```
1111110000000000000000000000000 => 1011101001000000000000000000000
                                   1011101001001110111001000000100
```

this is equal to:

```
1011101001000000000000000000000    1011101001000000000000000000000
-------------------------------    -------------------------------
_111110000000000000000000000000 => _011111000000000000000000000000 f(5, 25) = 118756
_____11000000000000000000000000 => _____01100000000000000000000000 f(2, 24) = 301
_______100000000000000000000000 => _______010000000000000000000000 f(1, 23) = 24
________10000000000000000000000 => ________01000000000000000000000 f(1, 22) = 23
```

thus resulting 119104 'lost' cycles which are located above HI

Regarding LO, there is actually no difference in what direction we are cycling
so for computing LO we can do reverse cycling:

```
0000010100111000100101011010111    0000010100111000100101011010111
-------------------------------    -------------------------------
0000000000000000000000000111___ => 0000000000000000000000001110___ f(3, 25) = 2926
00000000000000000000000011_____ => 00000000000000000000000110_____ f(2, 24) = 301
```

Thus resulting 3227 'lost' cycles which are located below LO this means that

```
overall amount of lost cycles = 119104 + 3227 = 122331

overall amount of all possible cycles = F(6, 25) = 736281

N1 in range 43797207..1562866180 is equal to 736281 - 122331 = 613950
```

I wont provide the remaining part of the solution. It is not that hard to grasp the remaining part. Good luck!

Comment: wow... gotta love stackoverflow when you see answers with so much dedication like this one :)

Answer (score 2):

I think it's a problem in Discrete mathematics,
assuming LOW is 0,
otherwise we can insert a function for summing numbers below LOW,
from numbers shown i understand the longest number will consist up to 60 binary digit at most

```
alg(HIGH,k)

l=len(HIGH)
sum=0;

for(i=0;i<l;i++)
{
 count=(l choose i); 
 nwia=numbers_with_i_above(i,HIGH); 
 if canreach(i,k) sum+=(count-nwia);
}
```

all the numbers appear
non is listed twice
numbers_with_i_above is trivial
canreach with numbers up to 60 is easy
len is it length of a binary represention

Answer (score 1):

Zobgib,

The key to this problem is not to understand how rapidly the growth of K's pattern grows, but HOW it grows, itself. The first step in this is to understand (as your coach said) how binary numbers count, as this determines everything about how K is determined. Binary numbers follow a pattern that is distinct when counting the number of positive bits. Its a single progressive repetitive pattern. I am going to demonstrate in an unusual way...

```
Assume i is an integer value. Assume b is the number of positive bits in i
i = 1; 
b = 1; 

i = 2; 3;
b = 1; 2;

i = 4; 5; 6; 7;
b = 1; 2; 2; 3;

i = 8; 9; 10; 11; 12; 13; 14; 15;
b = 1; 2;  2;  3;  2;  3;  3;  4;

i = 16; 17; 18; 19; 20; 21; 22; 23; 24; 25; 26; 27; 28; 29; 30; 31;
b =  1;  2;  2;  3;  2;  3;  3;  4;  2;  3;  3;  4;  3;  4;  4;  5; 

I assure you, this pattern holds to infinity, but if needed you
should be able to find or construct a proof easily.
```

If you look at the data above, you'll notice a distinct pattern related to 2^n. Each time you have an integer exponent of 2, the pattern will reset by including the each term of previous pattern, and then each term of the previous pattern incremented by 1. As such, to get K, you just apply the new number to the pattern above. The key is to find a single expression (that is efficient) to receive your number of bits.

For demonstration, yet again, you can further extrapolate a new pattern off of this, because it is static and follows the same progression. Below is the original data modified with its K value (based on the recursion).

```
Assume i is an integer value. Assume b is the number of positive bits in i
i = 1; 
b = 1; 
K = 1;

i = 2; 3;
b = 1; 2;
K = 1; 2;

i = 4; 5; 6; 7;
b = 1; 2; 2; 3;
K = 1; 2; 2; 3;

i = 8; 9; 10; 11; 12; 13; 14; 15;
b = 1; 2;  2;  3;  2;  3;  3;  4;
K = 1; 2;  2;  3;  2;  3;  3;  2;

i = 16; 17; 18; 19; 20; 21; 22; 23; 24; 25; 26; 27; 28; 29; 30; 31;
b =  1;  2;  2;  3;  2;  3;  3;  4;  2;  3;  3;  4;  3;  4;  4;  5; 
K =  1;  2;  2;  3;  2;  3;  3;  2;  2;  3;  3;  2;  3;  2;  2;  3;
```

If you notice, K follows a similar patterning, with a special condition... Everytime b is a power of 2, it actually lowers the K value by 2. Soooo, if you follow a binary progression, you should be able to easily map your K values. Since this pattern is dependant on powers of 2, and the pattern is dependant upon finding the nearest power of 2 and starting there, I propose the following solution. Take your `LOW` value and find the nearest power of 2 (p) such that `2^p < LOW`. This can be done by "counting the bits" for just the lowest number. Again, once you know which exponent it is, you don't have to count the bits for any other number. You just increment through the pattern and you will have your b and hence K (which is following the same pattern).

Note: If you are particularly observant, you can use the previous `b` or `K` to determine the next. If the current `i` is odd, add 1 to the previous `b`. If the current `i` is divisible by 4, then you decrement `b` by either 1 or 2, dependent upon whether it's in the first 1/2 of the pattern or second half. And, of course, if `i` is a power of 2, start over at 1.

Fuzzical Logic

**Pseudo-code Example (non-Optimized)**

`{   var LOW, HIGH
    var power = 0`

//Get Nearest Power Of 2
    for (var i = 0 to 60) {
    // Compare using bitwise AND
        if (LOW bitAND (2 ^ i) = (2 ^ i)) {
            if ((2 ^ i) <= LOW) {
                set power to i
            }
            else {
            // Found the Power: end the for loop
                set i to 61
            }
        }
    }

// Automatically 1 at a Power of 2
    set numOfBits to 1
    array numbersWithPositiveBits with 64 integers = 0
// Must create the pattern from Power of 2
    set foundLOW to false 
    for (var j = (2^power) to HIGH) {
        set lenOfPatten to (power + 1)
    // Don't record until we have found the LOW value
        if ((foundLOW is false) bitAND (j is equal to LOW)) {
            set foundLOW to true
        }
    // If j is odd, increment numOfBits
        if ((1 bitAND j) is equal to 1) {
            increment numOfBits
        }
        else if (j modulus 4 == 0) {
                decrement numOfBits accordingly //Figure this one out yourself, please
        }
        else if ((j - (2^power)) == (power + 1)) {
        // We are at the next power
            increment power
        // Start pattern over
            set numOfBits to 1 
        }
    // Record if appropriate
        if (foundLOW is equal to true) {
            increment element numOfBits in array numbersWithPositiveBits
        }
    }

// From here, derive your K values.

Comment: Select the code and click the 010101 button to format it properly.

Comment: Formatting fixed... Sorry about that.

Answer (score 0):

You can solve this efficiently as follows:

```
ret = 0;
for (i = 1; i <= 64; i++) {
  if (computeK(i) != desiredK) continue;
  ret += numBelow(HIGH, i) - numBelow(LO - 1, i);
}
return ret;
```

The function `numBelow(high, numSet)` computes the number of integers less than or equal to `high` and greater than zero that have `numSet` bits set. To implement `numBelow(high, numSet)` efficiently, you can use something like the following:

```
numBelow(high, numSet) {
  t = floor(lg(high));
  ret = 0;
  if (numBitsSet(high) == numSet) ret++;
  while (numSet > 0 && t > 0) {
    ret += nchoosek(t - 1, numSet);
    numSet--;
    while (--t > 0 && (((1 << t) & high) == 0));
  }
  return ret;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a full working example with c++17

```cpp
#include <bits/stdc++.h>

using namespace std;

#define BASE_MAX 61

typedef unsigned long long ll;

ll combination[BASE_MAX][BASE_MAX];

vector<vector<ll>> NK(4);

int count_bit(ll n) {
    int ret = 0;
    while (n) {
        if (n & 1) {
            ret++;
        }
        n >>= 1;
    }

    return ret;
}

int get_leftmost_bit_index(ll n) {
    int ret = 0;
    while (n > 1) {
        ret++;
        n >>= 1;
    }
    return ret;
}

void pre_calculate() {
    for (int i = 0; i < BASE_MAX; i++)
        combination[i][0] = 1;
    for (int i = 1; i < BASE_MAX; i++) {
        for (int j = 1; j < BASE_MAX; j++) {
            combination[i][j] = combination[i - 1][j] + combination[i - 1][j - 1];
        }
    }

    NK[0].push_back(1);
    for (int i = 2; i < BASE_MAX; i++) {
        int bitCount = count_bit(i);
        if (find(NK[0].begin(), NK[0].end(), bitCount) != NK[0].end()) {
            NK[1].push_back(i);
        }
    }
    for (int i = 1; i < BASE_MAX; i++) {
        int bitCount = count_bit(i);
        if (find(NK[1].begin(), NK[1].end(), bitCount) != NK[1].end()) {
            NK[2].push_back(i);
        }
    }
    for (int i = 1; i < BASE_MAX; i++) {
        int bitCount = count_bit(i);
        if (find(NK[2].begin(), NK[2].end(), bitCount) != NK[2].end()) {
            NK[3].push_back(i);
        }
    }
}


ll how_many_numbers_have_n_bit_in_range(ll lo, ll hi, int bit_count) {
    if (bit_count == 0) {
        if (lo == 0) return 1;
        else return 0;
    }

    if (lo == hi) {
        return count_bit(lo) == bit_count;
    }

    int lo_leftmost = get_leftmost_bit_index(lo); // 100 -> 2
    int hi_leftmost = get_leftmost_bit_index(hi); // 1101 -> 3

    if (lo_leftmost == hi_leftmost) {
        return how_many_numbers_have_n_bit_in_range(lo & ~(1LL << lo_leftmost), hi & ~(1LL << hi_leftmost),
                                                    bit_count - 1);
    }

    if (lo != 0) {
        return how_many_numbers_have_n_bit_in_range(0, hi, bit_count) -
               how_many_numbers_have_n_bit_in_range(0, lo - 1, bit_count);
    }

    ll ret = combination[hi_leftmost][bit_count];

    ret += how_many_numbers_have_n_bit_in_range(1LL << hi_leftmost, hi, bit_count);

    return ret;
}

int main(void) {
    pre_calculate();

    while (true) {
        ll LO, HI;
        int X;
        scanf("%lld%lld%d", &LO, &HI, &X);
        if (LO == 0 && HI == 0 && X == 0)
            break;

        switch (X) {
            case 0:
                cout << (LO == 1) << endl;
                break;
            case 1: {
                int ret = 0;
                ll power2 = 1;
                for (int i = 0; i < BASE_MAX; i++) {
                    power2 *= 2;

                    if (power2 > HI)
                        break;
                    if (power2 >= LO)
                        ret++;
                }
                cout << ret << endl;
                break;
            }
            case 2:
            case 3:
            case 4: {
                vector<ll> &addedBitsSizes = NK[X - 1];

                ll ret = 0;

                for (auto bit_count_to_added: addedBitsSizes) {
                    ll result = how_many_numbers_have_n_bit_in_range(LO, HI, bit_count_to_added);
                    ret += result;
                }

                cout << ret << endl;
                break;
            }
            default:
                cout << 0 << endl;
                break;
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```